# EmguCV Video Writer - make sure you have the specific codec installed

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to write video in EmguCV with the Video Writer class. When i run the following code

```
FPS = Convert.ToInt32(video.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps));
int height = Convert.ToInt32(video.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight));
int width = Convert.ToInt32(video.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameWidth));

vw = new VideoWriter(path, -1, FPS, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height), true);
```

I get the exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Unable to create VideoWriter. Make
>   sure you have the specific codec installed'

If i read correctly, the parameter `-1` is supposed to bring up an input box where you choose the codec. It doesnt. 
Also, if i put this inside the function instead of -1

```
int compression = Convert.ToInt32(video.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FourCC));
vw = new VideoWriter(path, compression, FPS, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height), true);
```

I get the same error. Same happens if i leave out the compression paramter completely.
Am i missing codes? If so where can i download them (and i need the video to be LOSSLESS).